# Bootstrap columns acting oddly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm creating an exercise for schools so a teacher can fill in a form which makes an exercise for their students. Now I'm trying to use a bootstrap columns to make things look better and more understandable where I'm going for this format:

SELECT1 - QUESTION

SELECT2

Now I thought I could achieve this by giving SELECT1 a col-md-3, QUESTION a col-md-7 and SELECT2 a col-md-10 which also gives them appropriate lengths for what they show. Now for some reason this stacks them vertically while giving them the appropiate length for their given cols. To make it even weirder if I shorten SELECT2 to for example col-md-3 like SELECT1 it will put QUESTION and SELECT2 on the same line. I tried putting them in a form with the class form-inline but that somehow made it like this:

QUESTION - SELECT1

SELECT2

which makes even less sense to me. I should note this is all inside a row which is inside a class with the styling for 10px padding left and right which is inside a panel panel-body which is inside a container.

Here is the relevant HTML code at the point where they're all just stacked vertically:

```
<span id="spanid">
 <div class="form-group input-group col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose</option> 
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="well well-sm col-md-7">
  <h5 id="eQuestion">A question</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group input-group col-md-10">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose the correct answer</option>
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
</span>
```

TL;DR: To get to the point as suggested how do I fix my code to get my page to look like this:

SELECT1 - QUESTION

SELECT2

EDIT for new code:

```
<span id="vqaspan" class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="well well-sm col-md-7">
  <h5 id="eQuestion">Question</h5>
 </div><div class="form-group col-md-10">
 <select class="form-control">
  <option disabled="" selected="">Choose</option>
</span>
```

This gives me:

SELECT2

SELECT1 - QUESTION

I don't understand why SELECT2 is now being placed above the rest

Comment: Bootstrap columns need to be children of a `.row` element to work properly. (And if you really think you can nest divs and headlines into a span element - then you might need to go learn some HTML basics first?)

Comment: Be more to the point.

Comment: @CBroe I noted in the post (before my edits) that it is "all inside a row", the row element is a div with the class row which is the parent of the span. Maybe if I said row element it would've been clearer but I feel like it should still be obvious enough without that one word.

Comment: So what, a child and a descendant are still different things. Plus, you are supposed to show a proper [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the element are coming in stack due to properties of class `input-group`. You can remove that to make it works as per your design requirement.

```
<span id="spanid">
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose</option> 
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="well well-sm col-md-7">
  <h5 id="eQuestion">A question</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group  col-md-10">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose the correct answer</option>
   <option>Option 1</option>
   <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
 </div>
</span>
```

Since you are using `col-md-3` column grid will works only at or above medium level devices

As per your modification in code.This works well at my end.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
<span id="vqaspan" class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <select class="form-control">
   <option disabled="" selected="">Choose1</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div class="well well-sm col-md-7">
  <h5 id="eQuestion">Question</h5>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-md-10">
 <select class="form-control">
  <option disabled="" selected="">Choose2</option>
  </select>
  </div>
</span>
```

It is giving unexpected behavior cause you might have missed to close select and div at the end.

Comment: This gets me very close to the solution but the issue that I'm now faced with is that SELECT1 and QUESTION are next to eachother as I wanted but SELECT2 is now somehow on top while in inspect element it's below SELECT1 and QUESTION.

Comment: Couldn't get where on top. Can you please share working code. So that I can debug into that to look for issue.

Comment: Updated my answer, please check if that help you.

Comment: I accidentally got rid of the closing div and select while copying it onto the site but they are closed on in my actual code. Ill check any CSS that might be interfering with this because the that part of the code is the same as mine and obviously your snippet works but for some reason my code doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, If possible share code with more info (styling). Either share the demo url where problem can be seen.

Comment: @KevinDijkstra, If that's works well please do accept and upvote. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that you are asking about bootstrap here specifically, but if I may indulge in a little "you should use this instead", how about just using pure HTML capabilities (flexbox)?  This type of scenario is what it's for (indeed, bootstrap 4 is now built with flexbox), and as you can see it's actually much simpler than bootstrap's infuriatingly hard to get right and darn near unreadable "col-md-x" css approach.

In this example, pared down for readability, we put `flex-grow:2` on the `select` in the first row and `flex-grow:1` on the `h5`, which achieves, more or less, the 2/3 and 1/3 ratios that you appear to want:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#row1 select {
  flex-grow: 2;
}

#row1 h5 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#row2 select {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row1">
  <select>
    <option>Choose</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
  <h5>A question</h5>
</div>
<div class="row" id="row2">
  <select>
    <option>Choose the correct answer</option>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I do like the idea of something more simple then bootstrap's col-x-x but not only is this for schools, it's also something I have to make for my own education (students make them and my education sells what we made if it's good) and they are in love with everything bootstrap 3 and therefore we have to use it aswell to be "in line" with all the other web applications from them. Thanks for the suggestion though, ill probably use it in the future.